# Is it ok to use PreferenceActivity with custom HashMap as settings storage in Android?

Tags: android, settings, preferenceactivity

I was using a json file for settings on my applications on other platforms. As i want to keep the flow similar, i ported my custom settings solution (which saves keys in HashMap and saves to / restores from a json file. It works perfectly.

Now, it's time to draw the interface for the settings.
I have 2 options:

**a)** Build a custom ListView and manage rows manually according to it's settings. (Basically somewhat similar to reimplementing PreferenceActivity which reads from xml)

**b)** Using PreferenceActivity without any xml (all inside the java code) but saving any changes to my own Settings storage instead of SharedPreferences..

Is it ok to use an alternative storage to save settings if i try to manage them via PreferenceActivity?

- **If so**, how to intercept and redirect to MySettings.save(..) function, instead of SharedPreferences' save function.
- **If not**, what should i do instead?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this in the end?  I have a similar goal (binary settings file/data model that I have ported from iOS).

Comment: @Pete I've written a wrapper class, so I can change my mind anytime later by just changing the contents of the wrapper class. But for the answer: I did not use SharedPreferences. I save it manually to file and read it from there.

Comment: I've gone down the route of using an abstract subclass of BaseAdapter that offers some convenience functions for creating rows for a ListView and additionally requests items with a section/row scheme more similar to iOS.  It also handles section headers.  I can then re-use this for the multitude of such screens that I need to display.

Answer (score 1):

Its ok to use anything that works, its your app.  The standard is to use SharedPreferences, which are built into Preferences (they automatically save to disk) and can be easily read/altered in other activities.  Why code in HashMaps and custom exports/imports to disk when you don't have to?

Comment: I use custom SharedPreferences alternative because of the shared code and settings file between android and non-android platforms.

Comment: How can i redirect save calls? Where should i intercept save commands? I just have to call MyPreferences.getInstance().set("key","value") in my custom class.

Comment: He clearly explained why he doesn't want to use the built in settings.  This doesn't answer the question at all.